# How to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin^{-1} x}{x} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How to prove this? Is there any geometrical proof? I have proved , btw, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ by Sandwich Theorem and little geometry.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: Reduce to the one you know: let $\theta=\sin^{-1} x$; then the limit is of $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometric intuition is that when $x$ is infinitesimal, $\theta$ is really close to $x$ as the picture indicated (recall that $\theta$ equals arc length when radius is $1$)

[image]

I really don't know how geometry can actually *prove* something about limit. If you want to figure this limit out, simply use L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\arcsin x}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{(\arcsin x)'}{x'} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1$$

Comment: FYI, this is one of those "assuming the consequent" proofs. If you know the derivative of $\arcsin$, then just write down the definition of $\arcsin' 0$.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro I just want to add the "let $\theta=\arcsin x$" method and I saw 2mkgz has already mentioned in comment. Should I still edit my post? Then it looks like plagiarism. I am a new user and not sure about all rules of the site.

Comment: It's not plagiarism to flesh out an answer in a comment, especially if you add credit to the user in your answer. I'm not saying the solution approach is *wrong*, only that it should be used with care depending on what is previously known. Mostly I would avoid writing exactly the same thing as another answer, but if you think you have something to add to one of the approaches then go for it.

Answer (score 5):

you already have $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t}  = 1.$$  we will make a change of variable $$\sin t = x, t = \sin^{-1} x $$  so that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}(x)}{x} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{\sin t} = 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use 
$$ \sin(x) < x  < \tan(x)$$
to show that for $0<x$ we have 
$$\sin^{-1}(x)\sqrt{1-x^2} < x < \sin^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'hospital's Rule.

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} {{f(x)} \over {g(x)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} {{f'(x)} \over {g'(x)}}\;\;\;\;\;If\;\;\;\;\;\;{{f(a)} \over {g(a)}} = {0 \over 0}\;or\;{\infty  \over \infty }$$

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{{{\sin }^{ - 1}}x} \over x} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {1 \over {\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} }} = 1$$